# Refactoring breaks initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mobx-react

React (from create-react-app) with MobX. Using axios for async backend API calls.

This code works. The initial state (array of issues) is populated, and the webpage presenting this component renders with initial content from state.

```
import { observable, computed, autorun, reaction } from 'mobx'
import axios from 'axios'

class IssuesStore {
  @observable issues = []

  constructor() {
    autorun(() => console.log("Autorun:" + this.buildIssues))

    reaction(
      () => this.issues,
      issues => console.log("Reaction: " + issues.join(", "))
    )
  }

  getIssues(data) {
    return data.map((issue) => ({title: issue.name, url: issue.url, labels: issue.labels}))
  }

  @computed get buildIssues() {
    const authToken = 'token ' + process.env.REACT_APP_GH_OAUTH_TOKEN

    axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${process.env.REACT_APP_GH_USER}/gh-issues-app/issues`,
                  { 'headers': {'Authorization': authToken} })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.issues = this.getIssues(response.data)
        return this.issues
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      })
  }
}

export default IssuesStore
```

In an attempt to separate API invocation promises from individual components and stores, I pulled out the axios call into a separate js file, as a collection of functions:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const authToken = 'token ' + process.env.REACT_APP_GH_OAUTH_TOKEN

export function loadIssues() {
  return this.apiPromise(
    `https://api.github.com/repos/${process.env.REACT_APP_GH_USER}/gh-issues-app/issues`,
    { 'headers': {'Authorization': authToken} }
  )
}

export function apiPromise(endpoint, options) {
  return axios.get(endpoint, options)
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
        return response.data.map((issue) => ({title: issue.name, url: issue.url, labels: issue.labels}))
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      })
}
```

Now, my store looks like this:

```
import { observable, computed, autorun, reaction } from 'mobx'
import * as github from '../api/github'

class IssuesStore {
  @observable issues = []


  constructor() {
    autorun(() => console.log("Autorun:" + this.buildIssues))

    reaction(
      () => this.issues,
      issues => console.log("Reaction: " + issues.join(", "))
    )
  }

  @computed get buildIssues() {
    this.issues = github.loadIssues().data
    return this.issues
  }
}

export default IssuesStore
```

Much smaller... but the webpage now throws an error because it now sees the initial state of `issues` as `undefined` on first render.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

The promise completes successfully later on (as it should), but by then it's too late. Sure, I can set up a few `null` checks in my rendering components to not run `.map` or other such functions on empty or as-yet-undefined variables.

But why does the code work with no initial rendering errors before the refactoring, and not after? I thought the refactoring was effectively maintaining the same logic flow, but I must be missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your refactored version

`github.loadIssues().data`

Is always going to be undefined because the data property on that Promise will always be undefined.

In the original version, `this.issues` was only ever set once data returned from the api, so the only values that it was ever set to were the initial value [] and the filled array from the api response.

In yours, the three states are [] -> undefined -> and the filled array.

`buildIssues` should look something like this:

```
@computed get buildIssues() {
    github.loadIssues().then((data) => {
      this.issues = data
    }).catch((err) => {
      // handle err.
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked. My understanding of promises wasn't good enough to understand why I needed another `.then()` on the returned promise to get my data. I assumed the `.then()` defined in the promise itself was sufficient to fetch what I needed inside the response.